# bxSlider issue in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

Not sure what is going on, but in Firefox my bxSlider is doing some crazy things, view it here to see what I mean [here](http://icodeinpink.com/inland/?p=30) I'm not sure what else I need to do.. seems to work alright in the other browsers.

Answer (score 6):

I also had a problem with `BX-Slider` but I had floating elements above, so I just used `clear:both;` on bx container.

Answer (score 0):

For friends who still have problems. just use the following code after the bxslider is load.
if lets say your slider is bxsliderGallery.change height of the image in each slider to your appropraite height. In my case it was 81px. then move the next and prev according to height.

```
if($.browser.mozilla)
 {
                 $('.bxsliderGallery').parents('.bxwrapper').find('img').css('height','81px');

}
```